# python 3.9 logging module. How to limit stack trace output from loging.debug()

Tags: python-3.x, exception, logging

I currently am using the python logging module to log some of the potential errors/exceptions. However, there is an exception that I catch and output with log.debug which I do not want the whole stack trace (it's massive).

We have reviewed the exception and are fine just noting that it has happen, it does not affect the system or flow of the program.

```
        except sql_a.exc.IntegrityError:
            self.log.debug('insertion of non-unique row', df.iloc[[row]],
                    stack_info=False, exc_info=False)
```

Regarding the code snippet above, I have tried using exc_info=False and/or stack_info=False. However I am still outputting the whole stack trace after the except gets caught. I have read the documentation on exc_info and am assuming I am applying it correctly?

> If exc_info does not evaluate as false, it causes exception information to be added to the logging message.
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I went through a few stackoverflow posts on logging exceptions however I haven't really found what I am looking for/solved my issue, apologies if the question is repeated previously.

Edit:

> handleError(record)
> This method should be called from handlers when an exception is encountered
> during an emit() call. If the module-level attribute raiseExceptions is False, > exceptions get silently ignored.
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handleError

I have also tried setting the attribute (handleError) to false but I still get a full stacktrace output to stdout/stderr.

```
    stream_handler.raiseExceptions = False
    handler.raiseExceptions = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this error, because I haven't found a similar question/answer I am going to leave it up here. (Until someone decides to delete it, no hard feelings)

```
self.log.debug('insertion of non-unique row', df.iloc[[row]],
        stack_info=False, exc_info=False)
```

The issue is because I wasn't following the format of parameters accepted by the *logging.debug()* module.

```
debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

If I correctly format the parameters everything is good, for consistency sake I will just leave my current working example below:

```
self.log.debug('insertion of non-unique row:\n{}'.format(df.iloc[[row]]),
        stack_info=False, exc_info=False)
```